# How to handle dynamic urls that are at the same level in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have two types of content that I would like them to be accessed at the same url level.

1. **Page**:

   - mysite.com/about
   - mysite.com/contact
2. **Category**:

   - mysite.com/category-1
   - mysite.com/category-2

I would like to route to a method of a controller according to the specific type of content. Any idea how can I handle this?

My code...

```
Route::get('{slug}', function($slug) {

    $p = Page::where('slug', $slug)->first();

    if (!is_null($p)) {

        // How i can call a controller method here?

    } else {

        $c = Category::where('slug', $slug)->first();

        if (!is_null($c)) {

            // How i can call a another controller method here?

        } else {

            // Call 404 View...

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't overcomplicate your routes file, you can create one controller to handle it all for you:

Your slug route:

```
Route::get('{slug}', 'SlugController@call');
```

A SlugController to handle your calls:

```
class SlugController extends Controller {

    public function call($slug)
    {
        $p = Page::where('slug', $slug)->first();

        if (!is_null($p)) {

            return $this->processPage($p);

        } else {

            $c = Category::where('slug', $slug)->first();

            if (!is_null($c)) {

                return $this->processCategory($c);

            } else {

                App::abort(404);

            }
        }
    }   

    private function processPage($p)
    {
        /// do whatever you need to do
    }

    private function processCategory($c)
    {
        /// do whatever you need to do
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Antonio. I ended up doing the same solution you gave before seeing your answer, doing exactly what you suggested. With that I believe this should be the best and most intuitive way to handle this. What I was trying to do initially is to keep the context of the controllers. In my case I have a controller named GameController which handles all methods related to games. With this solution I would end up leaving the categories out of this controller, but as you said the routes end up getting less complicated, which is a good thing.